# SOAP Request format

Tags: c#, soap

I am trying to create a SOAP web service to use with a client.

According to the documentation, we have to create a web service with two methods that return certain information. I have created them without a problem, but I can not get them to fit the example format.

I have to say that for years I did not create any SOAP services (since Net 2.0) because I have been doing REST services for a long, so if you see any nonsense, forgive me.

The example request that there is in the documentation (the good one) is this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pag="http://pagorecibos.pagosrecibos.com/"> 
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <pag:obtenerImporte>
            <referencia>040</referencia>
        </pag:obtenerImporte>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

That's the format that my service want to recieve:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <obtenerImporte xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <referencia>string</referencia>
    </obtenerImporte>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The code of my service is this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class Service: System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    public string ObtenerImporte(ObtenerImporte obtenerImporte)
    {
        return "Hola a todos";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    public string RealizarPago(RealizarPago realizarPago)
    {
        return "Hola a todos";
    }

}
```

Class (the other class is similar):

```
public class ObtenerImporte
{
    [XmlElement("referencia")]
    public string Referencia { get; set; }
}
```

The difference is in the namespace and the prefix in node "obtenerImporte" but I can't resolve it.

I'm using VS2017 Community Edition y created the project using "ASP.NET Web Service" template.

Comment: Just change `http://tempuri.org/` to `http://pagorecibos.pagosrecibos.com/` and that would make it essentially equivalent xml (that is, without imported namespace, but then who cares, your service should accept that top payload)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is there an error message? Something else?

Comment: Thanx for your answers. The problem is that the format is not equal and, when I try to make a request with the "original" format throws an error (sorry is in Spanish):

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: No se puede controlar la solicitud sin un parámetro de acción válido. Proporcione una acción SOAP válida.
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!!. Adding and removing code.... suddenly it works :D. The right way to define the service is this (thanks @zaitsman for your clue):

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://pagorecibos.pagosrecibos.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    public string ObtenerImporte(ObtenerImporte obtenerImporte)
    {
        return "Obtener Importe";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    public string RealizarPago(RealizarPago realizarPago)
    {
        return "Realizar Pago";
    }
}
```

I hope that this solution could help other one.